# how to transform test data to pick same features as training dataset

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, scipy

simply, i am trying to apply same feature selection to test data as i did to train set, however test doesn't have  the same exact shape.

```
def get_important_features (X_train, Y_train, X_test):
    '''

    :param X_train: features of training set of type scipy.sparse.csr_matrix
    :param Y_train: labels of training set of type scipy.sparse.csr_matrix
    :param X_test: features of test set of type scipy.sparse.csr_matrix
    :return: 
    '''
    select_percentile = SelectPercentile(chi2, percentile=75)

    print(X_train.shape)
    print(X_test.shape)
    X_new_train = select_percentile.fit_transform(X_train, Y_train)
    #print(select_percentile.get_support(indices=True))
    X_new_test = select_percentile.transform(X_test)
    return X_new_train,  X_new_test
```

so training set shape `(836, 3188)` and test set shape `(633, 3187)` as you can see testing set does not has the same shape as training set however all i care about picking only features that exist in training set after applying `chi2`. Also, as you might know `X_new_test = select_percentile.transform(X_test)` throw value error `ValueError: X has a different shape than during fitting.` because of the reason i mentioned above. Is there any way i can extract theses features from `X_test` without using `transform(X_test)`?

**Note:** that input is csr matrix not a dataframe so i get this values from libsvm format document.

```
 train= load_svmlight_file(train_file_name)
 X_train = train[0]
 Y_train = train[1]
 test= load_svmlight_file(test_file_name)
 X_test = test[0]
 Y_test = test[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your function and it works. Make sure you are passing the data in a correct way. Below is the minimal example for your reference:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

# dummy data
train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, size=(50, 10)), columns=['A'+str(x) for x in range(10)])
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, size=(30, 9)), columns=['A'+str(x) for x in range(9)])

# assuming the last column is the target variable
X_new_train,  X_new_test = get_important_features(train.iloc[:,:-1], train.iloc[:,-1], test)

print(X_new_train.shape,  X_new_test.shape)
(50, 6) (30, 6)
```

Comment: input is sparse matrix not a dataframe, and that is why i have hard  time manipulate it